# Wrapping elements in groups

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of elements like so:

```
<div class="cols">
 <div class="col">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box fs"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box fs"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like to group the elements like this:

```
 <div class="col">
  <div class="g">
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="g">
   <div class="box fs"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="g">
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="g">
   <div class="box fs"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="g">
   <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying something along the lines of the

```
$('div.cols div.col div.box').nextUntil('.box.fs').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="g" />');
```

but it's just wrapping around the whole lot. It's really got to start at zero index then nextuntil it hits a .box.fs then wrap around everything before that. I'm unsure of how to convey that into code. Maybe someone else knows?

**Reason for this: I am attempting to create a multi/single column layout for a stylesheet to be used on desktop and mobile devices.**

Comment: Why not just edit the HTML? Might be nice to give some reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var start = 0;
var boxes = $(".cols .col .box");
while(start < boxes.size()) {
  var box = boxes.eq(start);
  var group =  box.hasClass('fs') ? box : box.nextUntil(".fs").andSelf();
  group.wrapAll("<div class='g'>");
  start += group.size();
}
```

Comment: This works. I'm going to see what other people come up with. If a better answer cannot be given I'm giving the answer to you.

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning: this is an ugly answer for an ugly question (no offense).

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/P5ydr/ and some code:

```
// first, grap all the .fs boxes
$('.fs').wrap('<div class="g" />');

var group = [];
$('.col > .box').each(function() {
    group.push($(this));
    if (!$(this).next().hasClass('box')) {

        // next one doesnt have box class, so wrap group
        var target = $('<div class="g" />');
        $(group).each(function(){

            // add each grouped box to a g container
            $(this).clone().appendTo($(target));
        });

        // insert g container before the first box from the group its replacing
        $(target).insertBefore($(group)[0]);

        $(group).each(function(){
            // remove each original box from the group
            $(this).remove();
        });

        // make way for a new group of boxes
        group = [];
    }
});
```

If at all possible, I'd rethink your situation and see if there's any better way to structure your content and adjust the markup so that pure css can handle the columns without such a gruesome javascript dependency.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to create a HTML/CSS layout. The layout on a desktop screen uses two columns, the mobile will have only one column. I have some javascript to work out the screen size and I'm adding the class "m" to the body if the width is smaller than x. The one stylesheet takes care of both layouts. Works perfectly fine.

What I'm trying to do now is to fit in boxes into this layout that fit across two columns in desktop mode, hence the box.fs. I'm trying to group them so the layout appears seamless. Obviously there is a JS overhead here..

Comment: Glad to hear that you've thought it through. My answer should accomplish what your question is after – its less pretty than wachK's answer, but I thought the comments would help you think through the process and make it easier to debug and expand upon if need be.

Comment: Thanks. I've decided against doing it having taken on board what you've said. I still need to get this done but doing this level of DOM manipulation is too much work what should essentially be quite a simple design. I'm just getting into mobile markup design so still learning what's what. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the outer box html code at the front and at the end with a simple .append and .prepend, and putting  before every box.fs div with prepend.